# Excel VBA - create 150 files based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create an Excel VBA that create 150 individual (blank) Excel workbooks with file names based on the cell values in A2:A151?

Many thanks!

Tried Workbooks.Add.Saveas but this would only work for the first workbook and not for any of the following workbooks

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you should show us what you have tried. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: When you create a new workbook, use `Save` to save it. Beside this, there is no big difference in creating one ore 150 workbooks (as long as you don't keep them open after creation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbooks.Add.Saveas` will work you just need a loop.

I also broke it into two lines so it can be assigned to a variable.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim newbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Me
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
            newbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsx"
            newbook.Close
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Perfect, that has worked! I only had to change the „With Me“ to „With Sheet1“. The Me did not work for me.